# Graphviz: allow nodes to occupy same rank

Tags: graphviz

Is it possible to allow constrain one node to be not higher than other? 
Regular edge constraints a node to be lower, `rank=same` forces the same rank, and I want to allow to node to be on the same level or lower than other node, but not higher. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

try rank=min for your first rank, rank=max for your last rank, and all other ranks as rank=same, and it might order the nodes for you.